# Nunjucks concatenates variables instead of summing them

Tags: sum, nunjucks

I would like to sum two variables with Nunjucks but the output is the concatenation of the value of the two.

I declare the variables as an array in this format:

```
setupCredits(
[
  {month: 1, value: 0},
  {month: 2, value: 0},
  {month: 3, value: 0},
  {month: 4, value: 300},
  {month: 5, value: 0},
  {month: 6, value: 200},
  {month: 7, value: 500}
]
);
```

I make the sum as follows:

```
{% set clearedMonth =  session.epayelp.credits[month].value + session.epayelp.paymentAmountForEachMonth[month] %}
{{ clearedMonth  | formatMoney }}
```

`session.epayelp.paymentAmountForEachMonth[month]` is equal to 1146.38 whilst `session.epayelp.credits[month].value` is equal to 200. The output is 200146.38.
Interesting enough if I swap the order the output is 1146.38

Comment: Try `{% set clearedMonth =  session.epayelp.credits[month].value | float + session.epayelp.paymentAmountForEachMonth[month] | float %}`. One of term is string so result is concatenation. You must force both terms to float.

Comment: It worked - thank you so much!